# htaccess - Rewrite only url for images / css / js

Tags: css, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use google drive to share static content to my site. How can I use htaccess to do that? I  only want to rewrite addresses for image, css and js files, so rest of the files from root folder should be serve from main server.

For example, I want to rewrite
www.adress.pl/template/mytemplate/image.jpg

www.adress.pl/template/mytemplate/css/some.css

to:

googledrive.com/host/0B4zbBxGUyY4NRFVlVU5/image.jpg

googledrive.com/host/0B4zbBxGUyY4NRFVlVU5/css/some.css

Is it possible?

Comment: Provide more examples for css/js redirections also.

Comment: Added in firs post.

Folder in google drive will be always same. 80% of files are in this folder www.adress.pl/template/mytemplate/(or subfilders in it) so it shoud be enough for start. 

For the rest of files - if i knew the rule, i should be able to adapt it to the rest of folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this rule as first rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^template/mytemplate/(.+)$ http://googledrive.com/host/0B4zbBxGUyY4NRFVlVU5/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```